# Copy sas to hive

Tags: hive, sas

I have a SAS table with Indexes.I need to create copy this table on HIVE. I am already created metadata this HIVE table in SAS without Index. Is it necessary to create Index as well on HIVE table to make sure this table are the same to in case of need copy this HIVE table to SAS?

Comment: if youre trying to copy data, you dont need index.Most of real scenarios doesnt need any index. Just sqoop it

Comment: What if need to copied back from Hive to Sas table? The lack of index will not occured any 'issuess' with data ?

Comment: If you copy using sqoop, having index in sas will make load slow. Whatever you have in hive will be copied to sas ( garbage in garbage out).

Comment: So, when in Hive table there will bo no index when I copy it to SAS table the index will be not created, right? Because I need to keep index as well

Comment: the sqoop is insert only process. so, if you have index, they will remain as is. hive will not drop them.